# Oracle Database Connection in Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Tried to set up connection from sqlalchemy, error shows 'cx_oracle not found'.
I have problem install cx_oracle so i use sqlalchemy instead.
any idea?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
engine = create_engine("oracle://username:pwd@127.0.0.1:1521/sidname")
```

Comment: which database you want to use?

Comment: You seem to have problems installing some software. Please provide facts and observations, i.e. what system you have, what you did and what results you received. Ideally, provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: cx_Oracle's latest version got renamed to python-oracledb.  Read [Using python-oracledb 1.0 with SQLAlchemy, Pandas, Django and Flask](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19) and [Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 with python-oracledb for Oracle Database](https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c) for syntax.  If you have install issues, read the python-oracledb [install doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).